# POST http://localhost:8000/pay 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel-8

I added this "`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`" to main blade file and '$.ajaxSetup' token to js file. all are fine. Check the codes again and again. but got this error after click the button. alert didn't show as i mentioned below.This is Laravel 8.Please help me as soon as possible..............................

**checkout.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.razorpay_btn').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
    });
    
    var firstname = $('.firstname').val();
    var lastname = $('.lastname').val();
    var email = $('.email').val();
    var phone = $('.phone').val();
    var address = $('.address').val();
    var city = $('.city').val();
    
    
    
    if(!firstname){
        fname_error = "First Name is required";
        $('#fname_error').html('');
        $('#fname_error').html(fname_error);
    }else{
        fname_error = "";
        $('#fname_error').html('');
    }

    if(!lastname){
        lname_error = "Last Name is required";
        $('#lname_error').html('');
        $('#lname_error').html(lname_error);
    }else{
        lname_error = "";
        $('#lname_error').html('');
    }

    if(!email){
        email_error = "Email is required";
        $('#email_error').html('');
        $('#email_error').html(email_error);
    }else{
        email_error = "";
        $('#email_error').html('');
    }

    if(!phone){
        phone_error = "Phone Number is required";
        $('#phone_error').html('');
        $('#phone_error').html(phone_error);
    }else{
        phone_error = "";
        $('#phone_error').html('');
    }
    
    if(!address){
        address_error = "Address is required";
        $('#address_error').html('');
        $('#address_error').html(address_error);
    }else{
        address_error = "";
        $('#address_error').html('');
    }
    
    if(!city){
        city_error = "First Name is required";
        $('#city_error').html('');
        $('#city_error').html(city_error);
    }else{
        city_error = "";
        $('#city_error').html('');
    }
    
    if(fname_error!='' || lname_error!='' || email_error!='' || phone_error!='' || address_error!='' || city_error!=''){
        return false;
    }else{
        var data= {
            'firstname':firstname,
            'lastname':lastname,
            'email':email,
            'phone':phone,
            'address':address,
            'city':city
        }
        
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/pay",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.total_price);
            },
            
        });
    }
    
    
});
```

});

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/pay','Frontend\CheckoutController@pay');
```

**checkout.blade.php**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pay_btn">Ryzorpay</button>
```

**CheckoutController.php**

```
public function pay(Request $request){
    $cartitem = Cart::where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();
    $total_price = 0;
    foreach($cartitem as $item){
        $total_price += $item->products->selling_price*$item->product_quantity;
       
    }

    $firstname = $request->input('firstname');
    $lastname = $request->input('lastname');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $phone = $request->input('phone');
    $address = $request->input('address');
    $city = $request->input('city');

    return response()->json([
        'firstname'=>$firstname,
        'lastname'=>$lastname,
        'email'=>$email,
        'phone'=>$phone,
        'address'=>$address,
        'city'=>$city,
        'total_price'->$total_price
    ]);
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the exact error message you are facing and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: after I clicked the Ryzorpay button show POST http://localhost:8000/pay 500 (Internal Server Error) this error on console as I mentioned above.I need to get total price alert by click the button.But that alert wasn't came. @NicoHaase

Comment: Where's the full error message? Usually, when an error 500 occurs, there's something written to your server's error log. Also, `'total_price'->$total_price` looks wrong to me. `->` is not valid syntax

Comment: I change that.now after clicked the button doesn't show any error on console.but also didn't come the alert that has in js file. @NicoHaase

Comment: "doesn't show any error on console" - so, everything is working now? If not, please add more clarification to your question by editing it, including the error message thrown by the server

Comment: doesn't show any error on console.but ajax function doesn't call by clicking Ryzorpay button.Therefore alert doesn't show.I already put all codes above in question. @NicoHaase

Comment: An error 500 usually means that the server holds more debugging information. What does your server's error log tell you about this? If this is empty, try to use a higher error reporting level

Answer (score 0):

You must also send the _token field when sending the request.
so your code will change as follows :

```
var data= {
        '_token':"{{ csrf_token() }}",
        'firstname':firstname,
        'lastname':lastname,
        'email':email,
        'phone':phone,
        'address':address,
        'city':city
    }
    
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('pay') }}",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.total_price);
        },
        
    });
```

> **Do not forget to put a name for route like below**

```
Route::post('/pay',[CheckoutController::class,'pay'])->name('pay');
```

Comment: POST http://localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20route('pay')%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found) .Now got this error. @Ali Yazdanifer

Comment: Do not forget to put a name for route.

Comment: I changed my code as your code.but got this error POST localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20route('pay')%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found) @Ali Yazdanifar

Comment: Can you send me the image of your code on Telegram?

Comment: Js code?  @Ali Yazdanifar

Comment: js code and web.php... I think the command {{route}} should be used in the blade file and not in the js file

Comment: I think already added js file and web.php above in question